# How to scale things in OpenGL to real sizes?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to make a program in OpenGL 3.3. Everything is working, but the problem is that everything looks too small. I measured out my field of view in real life and I came to the result of 46.9°. So I applied that to my projection matrix like this:

```
projection = infinitePerspective(radians(46.9f), float(windowWidth) / float(windowHeight), 0.005f);
```

but it hasn't helped much.

I made a screenshot for you that shows a one by one by one meter cube that is 3 meters away from the camera:
[image: Cube 3 meters away]

If I measure out one meter in real life and view it from three meters away it looks way bigger than that. Is there some coefficient needed to scale everything, so that it looks real?

Comment: *"it looks way bigger than that."* -- Could you explain how you came to that conclusion? What is your method for comparing the apparent size of the object in real life vs the object on your screen? What size do you expect it to be on the screen?

Comment: @Romen Just by simply comparing it. I expect some coefficient that is dependent on the screen size(real world measurements)

Comment: @t.niese What do you mean?

Comment: @httpdigest I measured my view angle using arcsin not arctan with arctan I get 42°

Comment: @user11914177, Please humour me and try to explain *your method* for "simply comparing it". A formally defined approach to comparing an on-screen size to the real-life size you perceive will give us a framework to determine what the *correct* coefficient will be.

Comment: @Romen I laid down a one meter long ruler 3 meters away from my eyes. I remembered that size and then compared it to my program running on fullscreen on a 13" and 26" monitor.

Comment: @user11914177, How far away was your eye from the monitors you checked? Are you able to estimate a factor representing the difference you *did* see? Are you expecting the object on the screen to appear the same apparent size as in real-life, **or**, are you expecting it to occupy the same percentage of the field-of-vision (on screen) as it does in real life?

Comment: @httpdigest, There may be a fundamental problem with the question here that has nothing to do with the code. If I have a 3m wide TV, should the cube be rendered at 100% the width of the TV when viewed from *any distance*? If not, then there are real-life factors that make this problem impossible to solve without head-tracking.

Comment: @user11914177, To reiterate my question in the comment above. How big should the cube appear on a TV that is 1 metre wide when the user stands 3m away from the TV? Should it fill 100% of the width of the TV?

Comment: @Romen My 13" monitor is 58cm away from my eyes the 26" monitor is 70cm away. As you may have noticed, I have measured my view angle wrongly. With my correct view angle it looks better on both screens. I expect to occupy the same percentage of space.

Comment: @httpdigest How to feed the information in?

Comment: @httpdigest Yes, but how to use the four lengths measured? How do you get them into `infinitePerspective(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, a real scale is impossible. But with the right view angle it looks good.